# Android Studio adds unnecessary trash

Tags: android, size, apk, libs

I created empty project with empty activity, compiled it and saw apk size is about 1.4 mb. Seriosly? Nowadays "Hello, world" 's size is 10 mb and more.

After compiling there is many trash in `res` folder and `instant-run.zip`. How to exclude this garbage and reduce apk size at least to 300 kb?

Comment: remove appcompat support and you will get apk of size < 100kB

Comment: what's the size now?

Comment: 79 kilobytes___

Comment: now you can `Refactor > Remove Unused Resources...` but i dont think you will get much on size, only your project will be clean